# Format string but omit an argument if it is null

Tags: c#

I have a situation in production code, please see the following code snippet to visualize.

```
string formatStr = "{2} (FC {3:D3}): {1} {0}";
object obj= null;
string str = string.Format(formatStr, "", "10 - 15","Blabla", obj);
```

Output of this is going to be "Blabla (FC ): 10 - 15 "

Observe that there is no associated value with FC cause the obj was null, I don't want to print FC with nothing in it.

So what I till now thought was to inspect obj and remove the (FC {3:D3}): from it if obj is null, is there any other technique where I don't have to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build out the value for `{3}` in a separate step.

```
string formatStr = "{2}{3}: {1} {0}";
object obj= null;

string fcValue = (obj == null ? "" : string.Format(" (FC {0:D3})", obj));

string str = string.Format(formatStr, "", "10 - 15", "Blabla", fcValue);
```

Comment: I would go with this, Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I'd just have two different format-strings:

```
String str = String.Format(
    obj == null ?
        "{2}: {1} {0}" :
        "{2} (FC {3:D3}): {1} {0}",
//  0 , 1,       2,        3
    "", "10-15", "Blabla", obj
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a fan of over-engineering you could implement a [CustomFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter(v=vs.110).aspx). You introduce a special  composite format, feed the `String.Format` with your new format and CustomFormatter implementation and you're all set.

Your string format would look like this:

```
string formatStr = "{2} {3:NULL:(FC {{0:D3}})}: {1} {0}";
object obj= null;  
string str = string.Format(
    new NullFormatter(), // use our custom formatter
    formatStr, "", "10 - 15","Blabla", obj);
```

Notice the new  `{3:NULL:(FC {{0:D3}})}`. The customformatter is going to check for that `NULL:` string and then uses the `(FC {0:D3})` as a format string for that argument. The double `{{` and `}}` are needed to escape the `{` and `}`.

And the CustomFormatter looks like this:

```
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter(v=vs.110).aspx
public class NullFormatter:ICustomFormatter, IFormatProvider
{
    // IFormatProvider.GetFormat implementation.
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        // Determine whether custom formatting object is requested.
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }   

     // all formatting visits this
    public string Format(String fmt, object obj, IFormatProvider fp)
    {

      // if obj = null always return an empty string
      if (obj == null) 
      {
          return String.Empty;
      }

      // do we have our special format?
      if (fmt!= null && fmt.StartsWith("NULL:"))
      {
          // use the part after the NULL: as a formatstring
          return String.Format(fmt.Substring(5), obj);
      }
      else
      {
        // no, do normal handling
        if (obj is IFormattable) {
            return ((IFormattable) obj).ToString(fmt, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            return obj.ToString();
        }
      }
      return "?";
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't want to over engineer @rene :)
But thanks for the help, wish I could have enough privileges to vote you up.